# mouse hover on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having issues with jquery and css, maybe some of you can help me :) 
Here is my html code :

```
<html>
<head>
//myscripts
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cover").hover(function(){
        //the function i need to write
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="card">
    <img class="cover" src="cover.png" />
    <span class="detail" style="display:none;">
        More details
    </span>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <img class="cover" src="cover.png" />
    <span class="detail" style="display:none;">
        More details
    </span>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <img class="cover" src="cover.png" />
    <span class="detail" style="display:none;">
        More details
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the cursor is placed on the image, detail class(child of cover parent class) should fade in.
When the user moves cursor over the detail box, this box should not dissapear.
Please help me, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

1) **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** to handle when your mouse enter and leave an element.

2) **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** to find the next immediate sibling of an element.

3) **[.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)** to toggle between fade in and fade out

```
$(".cover").hover(function(){
    $(this).next().stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrWSf/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
$(".cover").mouseover(function()
    {        $(this).next().fadeIn();
    }).mouseout(function()
    {

       $(this).next().fadeOut();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a pure CSS solution. **http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/XN5uu/2/**

It uses the adjacent sibling selector to get the `.detail` element when the `.cover` element is hovered. It has surprisingly good browser support (IE7+): **[Support table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility)**

```
.detail {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s; 
}
.cover:hover + .detail {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hover()` function uses two methods one to mouse in & other two mouse leave. & use `closest()` to find in parent block.

```
    $(".cover").hover(function(){
       $(this).closest('.card').find('.detail').fadeIn();
    },function(){
       $(this).closest('.card').find('.detail').fadeOut();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using only css

```
.card {
    opacity:0
}

.cover:hover .card{
    opacity:1;
    animation-delay:2s;
}
```